# how to connect to multiple ISP using ethernet cable simultaneously

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ethernet

I have an ubuntu machine(with single ethernet port) and 2 ISP connections. Is it possible to -

- have additional ethernet port using external devices available in the market and make both(inbuilt and external) ethernet ports function? If Yes then please recommend some.
- connect to both the ISPs at the same time by connecting each ethernet cable to different ethernet port?
  Any response if highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

see solution from multiwan mikrotik with a random distribution of requests, But there will be problems with registration on the servers by binding by ip, another option is to register a static route